# C++ Expected an expression when defining struct with nested union

Tags: c++, struct, c-preprocessor, unions, preprocessor-directive

I have a struct with a nested union in c++, as follows:

```cpp
typedef enum {            
  VAL_BOOL,               
  VAL_NIL, 
  VAL_NUMBER,             
} ValueType; 

typedef struct {  
  ValueType type; 
  union {         
    bool boolean; 
    double number;
  } as; 
} Value;
```

I am trying to build a `#define` function to make initializing these values more readable, and this is what I have thus far, but it doesn't compile:

```cpp
#define NUMBER_VAL(value) ((Value){ VAL_NUMBER, { .number = value } })
```

The above implementation generates the following error at compile-time when the `NUMBER_VAL(val)` is used: `expected an expression`

The goal here is to be able to define a `Value` by writing something like the following:

```cpp
double dub = 1.23;
Value val = NUMBER_VAL(dub);
```

or pass it to a function, like so:

```cpp
void process_value(Value value);
...
double dub = 45.6; 
process_value(NUMBER_VAL(dub));
```

Is there some way to convert this `#define`*-ition*  into an expression that would let me use it this way? Or is my only option here to write a proper function to build these structs for me?

---

For the record, I know that the following would work, but I was hoping for something more succinct.

```cpp
Value NUMBER_VAL(double value) {
    Value val;
    val.type = VAL_NUMBER;
    val.as.number = value;
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Your code works for me on [online GDB](https://onlinegdb.com/ry4S2C9Y4). What compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using whatever comes with Visual Studio 2017
Visual c++ 2015 14.0.24215

Comment: C++ doesn't have designated initialisers. It also doesn't require typedefs. That all looks like C. Are you sure you want a C++ solution? A C++ solution would use constructors, not macros.

Comment: This is code being ported over from a C solution into a C++ solution. However, I was under the impression that C++ was actually a superset of C, so this is some of the latent C syntax. as @DeveloperPaul noted, this works in other places, so there must be some issues with my compiler and/or compiler flags. I'll probably just end up declaring `Value` as a class if I can't find the issue here.

Comment: Let `Value` be a struct and define sane constructors. It would end up achieving what you are after.

Comment: @aep, if you write that into an answer with a brief example, I'll accept it.

Comment: C++ is *not* a superset of C, and it does not have designated initialisers. GDB is not a compiler, so the fact that it accepts both C and C++ syntaxes is not relevant. And there is no difference between `struct` and `class` in C++ other than default nember visibility (`public` for a `struct` and `private` for a `class`).

Comment: C++ is a superset of a subset of C (this is true about any two sets by the way).

Comment: C++20 will have designated initializers; some compilers support it already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Live code](http://cpp.sh/5pps).

In C++ unions can have constructors. In your `struct` you can define constructor overloads to initialize the union member along with the union tag i.e. `type`.